# How to use withTimeout function to interrupt expression if it takes too long

Tags: r, timeout

I would like to terminate some code if a computation takes too long, i.e., it takes more than 2 seconds. I am trying to use the `withTimeout` function. Reading the example in the help, the following code is working and I get an error:

```
foo <- function() {
    print("Tic")
    for (kk in 1:100) {
    print(kk)
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
    }
print("Tac")
}

res <- withTimeout({foo()}, timeout = 2)
```

I tried to replicate this logic writing the following code, but it does not work, i.e., the computation ends even if the timeout has passed (on my laptop, it takes more or less 10 seconds).

```
res <- withTimeout({rnorm(100000000)}, timeout = 2)
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rnorm` example is a known "issue", which you can find on the [`R.utils` GitHub site](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/R.utils/issues/74) as a non-supported case.

You *can* make this work by doing

```
foo1 <- function(n = 1000000) { 
    ret <- rep(0, n); 
    for (kk in 1:n) ret[kk] <- rnorm(1); 
    ret; 
}

# The following will time out after 2s
tryCatch( { res <- withTimeout( { foo1() },
    timeout = 2) },
    TimeoutException = function(ex) cat("Timed out\n"))
#Timed out

# Confirm that res is empty
res
#NULL
```

Comment: thanks, I was trying to test the code and I couldn't imagine I stumpled upon this issue!

Comment: You're welcome @ciccioz; please consider closing the question by setting the green check mark next to the answer.